# Select ID's that have rows with NBR 1 and 2 on separate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am looking to write SQL that will return rows where a `VENDOR_ID` has both a row with `NBR_ID = 1` and another row with `NBR_ID = 2`. In the below sample, the SQL would return data for `VENDOR_ID` 93309A, a row with `NBR_ID` 1 , and the other row with `NBR_ID` 2.

```
GROUP_ID     VENDOR_ID    NBR_ID
AUX          27           1
AUX          87188A       1
AUX          92481A       1
AUX          92482A       1
AUX          92527A       1
AUX          93309A       1
AUX          93309A       2
AUX          93328A       1
```

I wrote the following SQL, but this doesn't specifically return `VENDOR_ID`'s with both a row with NBR_ID of 1 and another row with NBR_ID of 2.

```
SELECT GROUP_ID, VENDOR_ID, NBR_ID
FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE NBR_ID IN (1,2)
```

How can I update to only return `VENDOR_ID`'s that have these `NBR_ID`'s on distinct rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use correlated subquery

```
SELECT GROUP_ID,VENDOR_ID,NBR_ID
FROM TEST_TABLE a
WHERE exists(select 1 from TEST_TABLE b where a.GROUP_ID=b.group_id and 
a.VENDOR_ID=b.vendor_id and NBR_ID IN (1,2) 
having count(distinct nbr_id)=2) and NBR_ID IN (1,2)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: This seems to returning `VENDOR_ID`'s that have rows with `NBR_ID`'s higher than 2, i.e. It will return rows 1-4 if a `VENDOR_ID` has 4 `NBR_ID`'s, each on distinct rows. How can I just return `VENDOR_ID`'s that only have `NBR_ID` rows 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Thanks - Is there a way to also still select the `GROUP_ID` and `NBR_ID` columns as you had before?

Comment: Awesome, working as expected! Thanks again for the followup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT GROUP_ID, VENDOR_ID
FROM TEST_TABLE
WHERE NBR_ID IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY GROUP_ID, VENDOR_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT NBR_ID) = 2;
```

This does not return `NBR_ID` for two reasons.  First, your question doesn't specify that you want it.  Second, it is rather redundant, because you know the list consists of both 1s and 2s.

Comment: I added `NBR_ID` to the `Select` and `Group By` but then it does not return any data. I still want to display this column, and return both rows (with `NBR_ID` 1 and `NBR_ID` 2, respectfully).

Comment: Also this seems to be returning rows with more than NBR_ID 1 and NBR_ID 2, It's returning VENDOR_ID's with NBR_ID's, 3 or more as well. Ideally I only want to return ones that have only 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

use exists

```
select t1.* from TEST_TABLE t1
where exists ( select 1 from TEST_TABLE t2 where t1.VENDOR_ID=t2.VENDOR_ID
                                         and t1.GROUP_ID=t2.GROUP_ID
                                      and NBR_ID in (1,2)
                                      having count(distinct NBR_ID)=2)
and NBR_ID in (1,2)
```

Comment: This is not correct, it is returning rows per VENDOR_ID that have NBR_ID's higher than 2 (e.g. 3,4,5)

Comment: This still returns VENDOR_ID's that have rows with NBR_ID higher than 2 (e.g. 3,4,5).

Comment: @Nick check now